# Is it possible to use the transacted registry functions with a key loaded with RegLoadAppKey?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
HKEY root = RegLoadAppKey("myconfig.dat");
HANDLE transaction = CreateTransaction(TRANSACTION_DO_NOT_PROMOTE);
HKEY subkey = RegCreateKeyTransacted(transaction, root, "subkey");
```

The final call fails with error 6801 (ERROR_RM_NOT_ACTIVE).  I had assumed that the registry's resource manager would manage the loaded key, but perhaps this is not true?  Is there any way to make this work?